# How to enable lambda function to access APIs on EC2 instance over nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have create a server that provide APIs using nodejs program and using nginx for reverse proxy. I have set the inbound rules so that only specific ip addresses can access the APIs.

Now, I wish to create a lambda function which can access the APIs on that ec2 instance. I have assigned them into same VPC and security group. However, I got HTTP 502 response when I call the lambda function even though I have used try-catch block for the error.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const serializeError = require('serialize-error');

module.exports.translate = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("http://EC2-DOMAIN")
        return { statusCode: 200 };
    } catch( error ){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(serializeError(error), null, 4));
        return { statusCode: 400 };
    }
};
```

Is there any mistake I have made? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your config correctly, you may just need to add a rule in your security group allowing traffic on 80 (or whichever port you are running your api), referencing itself as the source.

[Here's a link to the documentation explaining this behavior.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-other-instances)

Resources are in the same security group cannot talk to each other unless there's a rule allowing them to do so.  To make it less confusing, you may want to think about creating a security group for your lambda functions, and adding a rule to your instance SG that allows traffic from your lambda SG on your api port.

Comment: I have opened the port 80 for specific IP address (My home and my Company).

Comment: For instances to talk to each other within the same security group, there needs to be a rule allowing that traffic.  I've updated the answer with a link to the documentation that explains it.

Comment: Tried to edit the other comment but I took long - So this would be a self-referential rule.  Security groups are like a template of port rules that are applied to each instance; they aren't a container inside of which traffic flows freely.

Answer (score 1):

The way you should approach this problem is :

1. See if lambda has permissions to talk to EC2 service, See [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html).
2. Next you should try to see if you are actually able to hit the API via lambda function by trying to log that call , a simple way would be to see if you are able to hit the ec2 via lambda on the Nginx port.
3. The above 2 steps will help you debug the issue if you have some permission or wrong setting somewhere.
   Let me know if till this you are able to do